# MS Access Atomic Transactions

Tags: ms-access, transactions, atomic

Is there any way to make microsoft access transactions atomic across multiple users?

I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711804(VS.85).aspx) which seems to imply that they are not, but I am wondering if atomicity in access is driver specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the footnote is only significant in the case of seriously disruptive failures (e.g. power or disk). If your concern is recoverability even at that level, you probably shouldn't be using access.

Comment: yeah we are using sql server as well but for the little people sometimes they dont have the resources to install it. concurrency will always be an issue with using a file based database. we have been able to minimise it by enforcing strict database constraints across most tables. but in the cases where we cant i would like to be able to stop multiple updates happening at the same time. using a file lock is not an option.

Comment: Footnote: Atomic transactions are not supported by the Microsoft Access driver. When committing a transaction using the Microsoft Access driver, a finite delay exists between the time the transaction is committed and the time the values are written to disk. This delay is determined by a delay inherent in the Microsoft Jet engine. The page timeout will not be less than a minimum value, even if the PageTimeout option is set below that value. As a result, there is no guarantee that committed data is stable, since changes may be made during the delay.

Comment: @Aran, by resources do you mean money?  http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx

Comment: nah we know about express. resources as in people qualified to install, set up etc. we will be looking into this further, see if we can make the transition painless for them.